# How to fix CSS background image not working?

Tags: html, css, linux, background, background-image

I am trying to place a background image for a personal webpage and I have yet to find any solutions for my issue. All I get is a white background.

File path for image: /personal-page/images/ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg

File path for code: /personal-page/style.css

Here is my code:

CSS

```
#hero{
    background-image: url(/images/ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Hero Section -->
<section id="Hero">
    <div class="hero container">
        <div>
            <h1>Hello, My Name is Isaac</h1>
            <a href="#" type="button" class="cta">Portfolio</a>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End Hero Section-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first change the id="Hero" in your html to id="hero" (with small h).
secondly change the path to a relative path in your css ./images/test.jpg (add the point)

html become

```
   <section id="hero">
        <div class="hero container">
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, My Name is Isaac</h1>
                <a href="#" type="button" class="cta">Portfolio</a>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
```

css become

```
#hero{
background-image: url(./images/test.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: top center;
position: relative;
 }
```

Comment: oh and be sure that your css file path is correct (try changing the p colors  to be sure)

Comment: The #Hero id was the problem. Spent hours trying to fix this over a capitalization error. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#hero{
    background-image: url("images/ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Seems like any type of quotation doesn't change the outcome.

Answer (score -1):

If i'm not mistaken this :

```
background-image: url(/images/ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg);
```

Should be this :

```
background-image: url('/images/ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg');
```

Comment: Applied it and nothing changed, not sure what it could be.

Comment: His actual issue is the ID is Hero with uppercased H and in the css he uses hero with lowercased h